# Не устанавливается сервис (служба) под Windows 2003

Tags: c#, windows-service, service, windows-server

Написана служба *на C# .NET4.0* (для работы с сетью и MSSQL) на борту которой трудятся несколько потоков.
Она без проблем ставится на Windows 7 SP1 x86 и прекрасно работает. Но как её установить под Windows Server 2003 SP2 x86 ?

Дело в том что при попытке установки службы выдаётся следующая ошибка:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Service\Service.exe' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515).
```

Службу устанавливаю через *bat*-ник:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM The following directory is for .NET v4.0.30319
set DOTNETFX4=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX4%

echo Installing Service...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
InstallUtil /i Service.exe
echo ---------------------------------------------------
echo Done.
```

В зависимостях службы прописана только библиотека *mscoree.dll*. Уже в её зависимостях прописано *KERNEL32.dll*, *USER32.dll*, *OLEAUT32.dll*, *ADVAPI32.dll*, urlmon.dll, *VERSION.dll*.
.NET Framework 4.0, а так же все остальные, в системе имеются.

Что ещё ей нужно, ведь приложение (*с теми же зависимостями*) с теми же функциями (*набором классов*) под этой Windows 2003 запускается нормально (*все функции выполняются корректно*) ?

PS Служба, как и приложение, писалось под Visual C# 2010 Express - т.е. шаблон проекта для службы создавал сам.

Comment: А что, если службу установить через "sc create"?

Comment: На msdn написано что службы, написанные на C#, устанавливаются через утилиту .Net - *InstallUtil*

Comment: Очевидно, что под `WS2003` не резовится какая-то из ваших `dependencies`. Сделайте лог [`Assembly Binding Log Viewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com//library/e74a18c4) и запостите его в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Service\Service.exe' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515).

В .NET (точнее, в Windows в целом) есть механизм отслеживания файлов, скачанных из "недостоверных" источников. Для .NET этот механизим включает Code access security, который ограничивает функционал, доступный из "недостоверных" сборок - например, создание файлов на диске или установку новых сервисов.

Если файлы сервиса на сервер скачаивался через браузер - то они будут отмечены как "недостоверные", вызвая именно такую ошибку при попытке установки. Причем проводник отслеживает "недостоверность" при распаковке архива, так что все из одного скачанного zip будет так же помечено как "недостоверное".

Для снятия блокировки нужно открыть свойства архива с файлами в проводнике, и нажать там unblock:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]